# GET returning multibyte string error

Tags: r, curl

I am trying to extract data from below URL but when I use GET it gives me below error. Can you advise me.

parenturl = "http://www.johnlewis.com/bose-companion-3-multimedia-speaker-system/p230405862?sku=230405862"

```
GET(parenturl)
Error in nchar(str) : invalid multibyte string 1
In addition: Warning message:
In strsplit(str, "\\\r\\\n") : input string 1 is invalid in this locale
```

Thanks,

Comment: I can't reproduce the error. `GET(...)` works fine for me with this url.

Comment: I do get the error (OS X 10.9.2, R3.0.3, httr 0.3) and `GET` isn't accepting the `encoding` option. However, `getURL(parenturl)` (via `RCurl` directly) does work. It might be the way you need to go (temporarily)

Comment: FWIW I'm using httr 0.3 with 64 bit R 3.0.3 on Win 7. No error with a freshly started R session.

Comment: Thanks , yes I am using OS X10.9.2 , i would need http status code, is there any other function other than GET(parenturl)$status.

Comment: You may have encountered this issue because of the incompatibility of system locale 
try setting the system locale with this code Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "C")